# What is the difference between std::tie and std::forward_as_tuple

Tags: c++, c++14

For a given class, if I want to write all the comparison operators, to avoid code duplication, I would write them something like this:

```
class B {
public:
    bool operator==(Type const& rhs) const {
        return as_tuple() == rhs.as_tuple();
    }

    bool operator!=(Type const& rhs) const {
        return as_tuple() != rhs.as_tuple();
    }

    // .. and same for other operators ..

private:
    auto as_tuple() const {
        return std::tie(a, b, c); // all the members
    }
};
```

I could implement `as_tuple()` there with `std::tie()` or I could implement it with `std::forward_as_tuple()`. Is there a difference? Which should I prefer?

Comment: Are you asking if it's better to refactor common code so that you can just call a function instead of copying the same code in multiple places? Yes.

Comment: @Barry Probably I am asking about the difference between std::tie and std::forward_as_tuple.

Comment: What do you mean "probably"? If the question is "what is the difference between `tie` and `forward_as_tuple`?" can you make that the question?

Comment: @Barry Saying more exactly, I did not quite understand what std::forward_as_tuple is. Currently my idea is that I should better implement as_tuple() with std::tie, at least it works fine.

Comment: Does that rewrite of your question match what you're trying to figure out?

Comment: @Barry Yes. Currently I replaced std::forward_as_tuple() with std::tie() in my code, but I am not 100% sure yet.

Comment: Would this code with `std::tie()` compile? Method is const but `tie` builds lvalue references.

Comment: @Slava Yes, the code compiles and works. I do not see a reason why I should avoid const lvalue references. They are something like const A &, that are good things, aren't they?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky I did not say they are bad, I had doubt it would compile, as `std::tie` should make lvalue refs. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's just look at the signatures. [`std::tie()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) is:

> ```
> template< class... Types >
> constexpr tuple<Types&...> tie( Types&... args ) noexcept;
> ```

whereas [`std::forward_as_tuple()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) is:

> ```
> template< class... Types >
> constexpr tuple<Types&&...> forward_as_tuple( Types&&... args ) noexcept;
> ```

The only difference is that the former accepts only lvalues whereas the latter accepts lvalues and rvalues. If all of your inputs are lvalues, as they are in your use-case, they are exactly equivalent.

`std::tie()` is largely intended as the left-hand side of assignment (e.g. `std::tie(a, b) = foo;` to unpack a `pair`), whereas `std::forward_as_tuple()` is largely intended to pass things around in functions to avoid copies. But they can both be used to solve this problem. `tie` is obviously quite a bit shorter, and arguably more well-known (the cppreference example for `tie` uses it to implement `operator<`), so that would get my vote.

Comment: "If all of your inputs are lvalues" there are no lvalues here, am I wrong?

Comment: @Slava We're doing like `tie(a, b, c)` where those are member names, which are lvalues.

Comment: That method is const, so `this->a` is not an lvalue and so on, is it?

Comment: @Slava It's still an lvalue... it's just `const`. Those concepts are orthogonal.

Comment: Yea got it, this terminology became so confusing over time. lvalue used to be what you can put on the left of `=` and now it all mess.

Comment: @Slava lvalue stopped meaning "left of assignment" somewhere in the 1970s, when it got into C

Comment: @Cubbi they should stop using term "lvalue" at the same time.

Comment: @slava think of them as **L**ovely values and pi**rrrr**ate values if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2020/10/16/tie-make_tuple-forward_as_tuple-how-to-build-a-tuple-in-cpp/) is a nice post on the same subject.

From the article in the link:

In summary, when you need to build a tuple, use:

1. `std::make_tuple` if you need values in the returned tuple,
2. `std::tie` if you need lvalue references in the returned tuple,
3. `std::forward_as_tuple` if you need to keep the types of references of the inputs to build the tuple.